# Local Server vs. Live Server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010

Im building this web application and while building it, I test, debug etc... locally through visual studio 2010 and it runs as expected. So now I'm at the point to put on a server at work to allow end users to see where im at in the development of the application and when I browse to the site on our intranet is runs extremely slow.

I have been doing some testing and it seem like the latency has do so with my connection to the database as when its runs simple select statements it takes at least 5 seconds to come back with the dataSet. Now just to give a little background I have only put it on the server once before and now this is my second time doing this.

A question you might have is how I put it on the server and the answer is that I published it to the server like it did the first time. Im using the same connection objects as I did for the first application I put on the server so I dont know how that could be the problem.

I know my question is vague but what im basically asking is how/where do I begin to look to try to solve this problem, as I have no idea where to start? And also I'm thinking that if there was a problem with the connection wouldnt it give me an error instead of being slow?

Comment: I really do not understand what is the main problem, I just understand that your pages are slow, but I do not understand where they run, where the database is, how you have connect the computer, is on intranet or on internet, I have lost you.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's very hard to answer your question (because of it's nature and amount of details), I would:

- debug application to find out where the lag is comming from
- use SQL profiles to find out query execution time etc.
- inspect your code and make sure handled exception is not being rethrown (empty try catch)
- inspect application log to make sure is exception free.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding. For example one problem that im seeing is that there is a lag from one of the dropdown boxes that puts all names from a table. The table currently has only 2 records so I dont know how something that small can take 10+ seconds to come back from the server.

Comment: can you post the code you use to get data from SQL server. also is that the case with every single query or only some (being slow)?